# How to use dream in combination with nightmare?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I know that dream can be used as a noun and as a verb. And I know that a nightmare is a bad dream.
My question is:
If I wanted to use dream as a verb and wanted to use nightmare as its object, would it be correct to say **"I dreamt a nightmare last night"** or **"I dreamt about a nightmare last night"**?
or the only way is to say "I had a nightmare last night" without using dream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The natural and usual expression is "I had a nightmare".  There's no grammar error in "I dreamt a nightmare", nor is there an error in "I dreamt a dream", but neither is idiomatic.

Similar "I dreamt about a nightmare" is not natural. It means that the "topic" of your dream was a nightmare, it doesn't mean your dream *was* a scarey.  Dreams can be odd, but I don't think I've had a dream in which I was concerned about having a nightmare.

So the only idiomatic expressions are "I had a nightmare" or "I dreamt about *a monster*".

Comment: Thanks a million.

Comment: What if I want to say it in a way to show it's my routine? Which one is correct: "I often have nightmares." or "I often dream nightmares."?

Comment: I often have nightmares.